# Recyclerview not scrolling after updating support libraries

Tags: android

I am using a recyclerview in my project. The project was using the following libraries:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0      
com.android.support:design:23.0.0       
com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0
```

The `recyclerview` was functioning as it should, e.g. scrolling. I decided to update my project to use `v7:25.0.0` of the same libraries in order to use the `DiffUtil` class for my adapter, associated with my `recyclerview`. Once I built and ran the project with the updated libraries, my `recyclerview` doesn't scroll anymore. I haven't integrated the `DiffUtil` class yet, so I know that isn't the problem. It seems it is to do with the updated libraries, as going back to the previous ones, makes my `recyclerview` scroll again. Your help would be most appreciated.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // replace with the current version of the Android plugin
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // the latest version of the android-apt plugin
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.6'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/tbruyelle/tbruyelle" }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.exam'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 29
        versionName "1.3.8"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    final STETHO = '1.4.1'
    compile "com.facebook.stetho:stetho:$STETHO"
    compile files('libs/classes.jar')
    compile('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+') {
        exclude module: 'answers-shim'
    }
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.10.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.1.jar')

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.github.android-s14:rve:1.1.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.github.android-s14:rve:1.1.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.eftimoff:android-pathview:1.0.6@aar'
    compile 'com.github.jorgecastilloprz:fillableloaders:1.02@aar'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    compile 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Core:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.tealium:library:5.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Compiler:2.2.1'
}
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}
```

Comment: please read  first **[ask]**

Comment: Add the Gradle file and a [mcve] please